# Does SSL communicate automatically using the most secure protocol available?

Tags: tls, webserver

As different version of the SSL protocol can be used to communicate SSLv2, SSLv3, TLS1.0, TLS1.1, TLS1.2 with different level of security of course my question is simple :

> Does SSL communicate automatically using TLS1.2 (for example : HTTP communication Client to Web Server where SSLv3, TLS1.0, TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 enabled on the Web Server)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SSL handshake ensures that the best protocol version supported by both client and server is chosen:
When the client starts the handshake it tells the server the best protocol version it supports. The server then responds with the best protocol version it supports which is equal or lower to the clients protocol version. The client will close the connection if the servers version is too low. Otherwise both continue with the best common version.